# Why is Maria listed twice in this 18th century church record?

Tags: birth-records, 18th-century, new-york-state, baptism-records, church-records

I see a Maria Lent listed twice in a church record shown at [Ancestry.com](http://interactive.ancestry.com/6961/42037_2421401574_0609-00191):

[image]

Also the year is unclear and entered twice there:

```
Name:   Maria Lent
Gender: Female
Event Type: Baptism
Birth Date: 10 Feb 1791
Baptism Date:   18 Sep 1791
Baptism Place:  Cortlandtown, Monroe, New York, USA
Father: Hendrik Lent
Mother: Maragret Lent
```

And also:

```
Name:   Maria Lent
Gender: Female
Event Type: Baptism
Birth Date: 10 Mar 1790
Baptism Date:   18 Sep 1791
Baptism Place:  Cortlandtown, Monroe, New York, USA
Father: Hendrik Lent
Mother: Maria Lent
```

Which one is it, why is she listed twice on the page and where is the baptism date shown?

Comment: Why do you think they are the same person? Both are called Maria and both have a father named Hendrik, but they have different birth dates and different mothers' names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the baptism date has been taken from the second date at the top of that page which is the first one not clearly marked as being a birth date.  They are in a column headed `Chd [= Child] & Date`.  It seems like the next name does not have a birth date and that 18 Sep 1791 is intended to be the baptism date for all subsequent baptisms until the next non-birth date is written.

[image]

On that page, there are 13 births recorded, and 5 of them are to parents with the Lent surname.  It seems like Lent may have been a common name in that community.  Previous pages have lots of Lent surname baptisms too.

Consequently, and in the absence of any other evidence, I agree with a comment by @HarryVervet that there appear to be two successive births recorded for babies named Maria to presumably two fathers, both named Hendrik, with women name Maria and Margaret, on different dates.

I am unfamiliar with the Dutch Reformed Church and searched Google for information about their position on polygamy, but that did not suggest that it was likely practiced.  Even if it were a single church-endorsed polygamous Hendrik, then I am also unsure whether naming two daughters, that appear to be born only one month apart, would be given the same name.